# DatePicker beforeshowDay event

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a dropDownList and based upon the value selected in my dropdownList, I need to change the layout of each date of my DatePicker.  Is it possible to launch the event

> beforeShowDay: function(dateToShow) upon a change in the dropDown List?  How can I achieve the above?

Comment: what do you mean with layout? could you give an example?

Comment: I am changing the display, using css for each and every date, based upon some control from the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your-drop-list").live('change', function(event){
    var date = new Date(2008,9,3);//generate date object based upon the value in input field using split 
    $('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", date );
});
```

Comment: I already have the foolwoing code:   $("#dateChoose").datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
  onSelect: function (dateText, inst)  {
           //
  },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) 
        {         
            //
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(dateToShow)
        {
            //
          }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, may be you want like this...
[DatePicker style Change.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#animation)

Comment: Can I have an example of how to override my existing datePicker?

Comment: you may change the datepicker {option, ...., ......} to whats you want.. for all options you need to see jqueryUI documentation..